# How is it called when you have 2 links that lead to the same page?

Tags: buttons, hyperlinks

I just logged into Mandrill, and I noticed their page has only 2 buttons "Get SMTP credentials" and "Get API Keys"

I also noticed these 2 buttons lead to the same place.

This is a great UX example in my opinion and I would like to use this as an example.

- They focus on 2 features. (I am sure they have a lot more, but they focus on the most valuable features for the user)
- They added an unnecessary page just to let the user know about these 2 features. I am sure all users who log into Mandrill immediately know their main 2 features. No documentation no nothing. I would pay a lot to get this in my products.

I am trying to educate myself about UX so my questions are:

- Is there a name for this technique?
- Are there any resources I can read more about this.

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're asking but your title is confusing. Can you re-word it?

Comment: definitely - can you suggest something?

Comment: I think you're saying, "Why do you have two links if they both lead to the same page?". I don't want to edit it in case I'm wrong.

Comment: No - I am actually excited about the 2 links. It educates the user in an intuitive way. I just want to know if the UX field has a name for this approach.

Comment: The same place or the same page? (The same place in the page or two separate places in the page.)

Comment: not certain place  - simply the same page.

Comment: Generally, this is simply how hypertext works. There's no real rule as to what links to what or how many links link to what. UX-wise, I'm not sure there's a particular name other than it's perhaps a couple of feature call-outs (that just happen to link to the same page). Of course, I'd question the need for the separate page. Why not just call out the two features on the landing page itself?

Answer (score 1):

Use redundant links with caution. The main drawback is that it adds cognitive load by giving the appearance of more destinations and choices than there actually are. When someone chooses one of the links, there's always a bit of brainpower consumed by to "Did I choose the right one?" and "I should remember to go back and try the other one later."

In the example you provide, the better solution may be to have a single button that includes both "smtp credentials" and "api keys," or to have separate buttons leading to separate, dedicated destinations. (I don't know enough about this specific domain and user needs to make that call.)